# Strange FIrefox input problem

Tags: html, css, firefox

Im having issues vertically positioning text inside of a text input field in Firefox. I have managed to get it to work in every browser except firefox:

[alt text http://img696.imageshack.us/img696/2247/picture18h.png](http://img696.imageshack.us/img696/2247/picture18h.png)

See how the 'Fwd:' text is crammed up against the top? I need to vertically center that inside the field.

Here is my css:

```
.subject {
clear: right;
font-family: Helvetica, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
height: 1.6em;
width: 500px;
font-size: .88em;
margin-bottom: 20px;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-top: 5px;
line-height: 1.5em;
padding-bottom: 0px;
}


.meta_str input {
float: left;
margin-left: 10px;
height: 1.6em;
border: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
}
```

HTML:

```
<li><div class="pre_box"><h4>Subject:</h4></div><input type="text" class="subject" value="Fwd:"/><div class="clear"></div></li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.subject is not inheriting some padding from elsewhere. Setting the line-height and the height to the same has always worked for me.

You could inspect the element in FireBug to see what styles are being applied.

Comment: Hmmm, this is strange - I have put it into firebug and doesn't seem to be inheriting anything that would interfere with the default padding. 
I wonder if there could be some other problem. 

For future refrence, the page I am talking about can be found here:
http://current-post.com/qmail/compose.html

Comment: Looks like you were right about the not inheriting padding - I got it thanks!